# How to know when actual audio is being played?

Tags: javascript, dom, html5-audio

I'm trying to know when **sound** is actually coming out from the user speakers, if that makes any sense.

I have the following:

```
const stream = new Audio("https://stream1.srvnetplus.com:18122/stream");

const loading = false;

async function play() {
  loading = true;

  // stream.play() returns a Promise<void>
  await stream.play();
  loading = false;
}
```

`loading` is set to false, but for some reason actual sound comes out of my speakers after 1 — 2 seconds in some ocassions.

[This](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-audio-player) react library (react-audio-player) has an event called `onCanPlay`. As per the docs state:

| Event | Type | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| onCanPlay | Function | called when enough of the file has been downloaded to be able to start playing. Passed the event. |

This makes me think that the *await* in `await stream.play();` is not enough to know when actual audio is being played. Correct me if i'm wrong.

I would like a solution that looks something like this:

```
const stream = new Audio("https://stream1.srvnetplus.com:18122/stream");

const loading = false;

async function play() {
  loading = true;

  const res = await stream.play();
  await res.ready();
  loading = false;
}
```

Comment: [`HTMLMediaElement.onplay`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/play_event) can be used with native browser `<audio>`.

Comment: any live example?

Comment: It seems that HTMLMediaElement.audioTracks is not widley supported amogst web browsers. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement#browser_compatibility 

From Chrome 37: this feature is behind the enable-experimental-web-platform-features preferences (needs to be set to enabled).

Comment: Can't repro: https://jsfiddle.net/ck4v53mg/ The Promise returned by `.play()` should be all you need. Please provide a [MCVE] with the browser's version on which you experience this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem with [howler.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/howler)

```
import { Howl } from "howler";

const streamUrl = "https://stream1.srvnetplus.com:18122/stream";

const stream = new Howl({
  src: [streamUrl],
  html5: true,
  preload: true,
});

const loading = false;

function play() {
  loading = true;

  stream.play();
  stream.on("play", () => {
    loading = false;
  });
}
```

Comment: Why is an external library needed? [`<audio>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio) has a [`play`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/play_event) event

Comment: native play return a promise. but when completed it doesn't guarantee that real sound is coming out of the speakers. Read the original question. Also remember that the audio source is a live stream from a radio station.

Answer (score 0):

All of the `<audio>` events could be logged and shown in the example below. The **`playing`** event fires after the audio playback begins.

```js
function initPlayback() {
  const audio = document.querySelector('audio')

  event.target.remove() // remove <button>
  audio.hidden = false;

  // log all events of <audio>, except timeupdate (too verbose)
  ['audioprocess', 'canplay', 'canplaythrough', 'complete', 'durationchange',
  'emptied', 'ended', 'loadeddata', 'loadedmetadata', 'pause', 'play',
  'playing', 'ratechange', 'seeked', 'seeking', 'stalled', 'suspend',
  // 'timeupdate'
  'volumechange', 'waiting']
    .forEach(name => audio.addEventListener(name, event => {
      console.log(name)
    }))
    
  audio.src = 'https://stream1.srvnetplus.com:18122/stream'
  audio.play()
    .then(() => console.log('play() resolved'))
}
```

```html
<audio controls hidden></audio>
<button onclick="initPlayback()" style="padding: 1em 2em;">Play</button>
```

Comment: But OP is awaiting for `.play()`, which does resolve after the `playing` event.